# How can I reproduce solarized theme colors with xcalib for reading pdf's

Tags: xorg, colors

How can I reproduce [solarized theme colors](https://github.com/altercation/solarized) with [xcalib](http://xcalib.sourceforge.net/) for reading pdf's? I want to use `xcalib` such that I can read (black and white) pdf's with `evince` such that the background is like that one I am used to from my emacs solarized (light) color theme and the font color is also similar to that of the emacs solarized theme.

So how can I reproduce this with `xcalib`?

I tried  `xcalib -red 1.5 0 65 -green 1.5 0 60 -blue 1.5 0 25 -alter` but it didn't lead to the desired result. I don't see how to adjust the values correctly to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I can't see a way to accomplish this using xcalib. I did however find this askubuntu Q&A titled: [How do you set system display color profiles in Xubuntu and Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu).

Seems like `colord` and `color-mgr` are the tools for this task.

Comment: I think that is for the colors of the widgets, but I want to influence the color of the background and font of the pdf page. I tried  `xcalib -red 1.5 0 65 -green 1.5 0 60 -blue 1.5 0 25 -alter` but it didn't lead to the desired result. I don't see how to adjust the values correctly to get what I want.